# Error in Oracle while populating a Datatable - C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, datatable

When I try to populate a `datatable` of a Oracle table  via .`NET`, I get error as

[image]

Here is the code that I used:

```
DataTable PRDTableResults = new DataTable();
using (OracleDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OracleDataAdapter())
{
  OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("SELECT * from PRD");
  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
  cmd.Connection = conn;
  dataAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
  dataAdapter.Fill(PRDTableResults);
 }
```

I am not sure why such error showed up. The `PRD` table has fields with no precision and scale defined but as `NUMBER`.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced this error before and I remember that it was caused by a bug in the Oracle ODBC driver. I don't remember version exactly, I think it affected for 10.2 and 11.2 version, and only in x64 bit driver.

So you can try this, set platform target from AnyCPU to X86 in properties of your application project.

Comment: Interesting! Thnx